# Does backbone do _.bindAll by default now?

Tags: backbone.js

[This tutorial](http://arturadib.com/hello-backbonejs/docs/3.html) suggests that we need to do `_.bindAll` to get the correct value of `this` in our functions. It seems that `_.bindAll` is no longer required with Backbone. The following code logs the same thing twice:

```
var TestView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () { _.bindAll(this, 'func1'); },
    func1: function () { console.log(this); },
    func2: function () { console.log(this); }
});
var testView = new TestView();

testView.func1();
testView.func2();
```

Am I correct in assuming that `bindAll` is no longer required, or am I just making a stupid mistake?

Comment: `testView.func1();` isn't a good test case, try it with some `events` to see what happens. The [official docs still talk about `bindAll`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-this) and I don't see anything in the change log about binding no longer being necessary.

Comment: Your example would work without `_.bindAll`, you need to use one of the functions as an event handler to see the effect of binding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is still necessary when the method is called out of context of the Class. Since you'recalling it in context, it isn't a mistake that you haven't needed it.

As mentioned in the underscore documentation for `_.bindAll` (http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#bindAll), it's "very handy for binding functions that are going to be used as event handlers, which would otherwise be invoked with a fairly useless `this`." You would also use it for methods where you need to create a callback.

To see how there are differences for callbacks, look at this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/joshvermaire/YQdZu/